# yii2 takes time to execute my php code

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

yii2 takes 4 to 5 min to execute the code after the one execution.
check browser cache, it not storing any cache.
Checked in multiple browser, happening on all(chrome and firefox - with incognito mode also).

Its not delaying the code execution but it takes time if i make change in my code and refresh the the page, it will execute the code after some time only.

Is there any tag or script which sets the time for code execution.

Tried below way as well :

```
 Yii::$app->cache->flush();
```

Did not help.
Anything else i can try ?

Comment: You look to another cache. If you have delay in reloading of your php code - you should check server settings. Can you please show your phpinfo() ? Do you have installed apc cache?